# How to store answers to a MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql

I want to take Stack Overflow as an example. Now, there's a question posted and let's say they store the following things to database.

`question_ID
question_title
question_body
question_asker
question_date`

But there are 2 things left, the comments and the answers. So my question is "How do I store them to the database?" I mean, I don't think that 5 or probably 10 article-like answers are stored in just a cell.

Comment: Take a look at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede for the details about Stack Exchange's schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answers and the commments will be stored in different tables, like so :

**Database**

questions

`question_ID
 question_title
 question_body
 question_asker
 question_date`

answers

`answer_ID
 answer_title
 answer_body
 answer_asker
 answer_date
 question_ID`

comments

`comment_ID
 comment_title
 comment_body
 comment_asker
 comment_date
 answer_ID`

Here is an example of PHP code fetching the data using [INNER JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp) :

**PHP**

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=stackoverflow', $user, $pass);
$query = 'SELECT * from questions INNER JOIN answers ON answers.question_ID = question_ID INNER JOIN comments on comments.comment_ID = answer_ID';
foreach($dbh->query($query) as $row) {
    print_r($row);
}
```

Complete schema of stackoverflow database : [Database schema](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede)

Answer (score 0):

You should read about relations, and database design.

For your example, database should store additional tables for comments and answers.

Each table should have additional column, for example question_id which stores key to corresponding question.

Comment: And there's another problem that some people think it can't be 'fixed'. When you delete a post/question from the middle, for example if you delete number 26 it will be as 25, 27... Then if that happens, there will be a huge dis-order. Is there a way to auto-order the id column or some other solution?

Comment: In your case, if this id 26 will be deleted do we need to shift all next numbers? no, we still can use does data. Sorting result will be the same. ID is just identification field, it don't need to be consecutive. Depending from DB, there are different mechanism in generating next value,mysql and sql servrer uses special column type, oracl uses sequences.